# Почему при передаче параметра в массиве POST, условие не срабатывает?

Tags: php

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo 'Всё ок!';
}

?>

<form action="" method "post">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Ничего не отображается, я уже облегчал, убрал, то что идёт после && и всё рано не работает, почему у меня постоянно не работают такие простые вещи?

Comment: Вы на кнопочку нажали? Проинспектируйте сам post запрос в браузере(F12 - Сеть).

Comment: много раз нажимал

Comment: Если с запросом всё нормально - читайте логи

Comment: в url данные передаются, а echo не срабатывает

Comment: Всё, увидел) Секунду

Comment: какие логи, где?

Comment: `method "post"` очепятка..........

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно указали атрибут method формы:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

А по умолчанию форма отправляет данные методом `get`, и в php искать его надо было в `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас просто не хватает знака равно...

method="post"
... очень сильно помогает дампить код:

```
var_dump($_POST['email']);
die();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]